# Rust Polars Dataframe String replacement

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I am writing a Rust using Polars. I would like to know how can I manipulate one string dataframe column.

For example, I have the following dataframe:

| Id | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Some foo text |
| 2 | Other text |

And I would like to replace all values that has "foo" by some other value like "new foo" and I wasn't able to find a way to do that. Can anyone help me on this?

I tried to use the function with_column, but I didn't manage how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like the following:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars::df;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    // use macro
    let mut df = df! [
        "Id" => [1,2],
        "Text" => ["Some foo text", "Other text",],
    ].unwrap();

    println!("before = {:?}", df);
    
    let re = Regex::new(r"foo").unwrap();
    let target = "new foo";

    let new_foo_series = df.column("Text").unwrap()
        .utf8()
        .unwrap()
        .apply(|e| re.replace(e, target));
    
    let df2 = df.with_column(new_foo_series).unwrap();
    
    println!("after = {:?}", df2);

}
```

That will show:

```
before = shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────┐
│ Id  ┆ Text          │
│ --- ┆ ---           │
│ i32 ┆ str           │
╞═════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ Some foo text │
│ 2   ┆ Other text    │
└─────┴───────────────┘
after = shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────────┐
│ Id  ┆ Text              │
│ --- ┆ ---               │
│ i32 ┆ str               │
╞═════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ Some new foo text │
│ 2   ┆ Other text        │
└─────┴───────────────────┘
```

Ref = https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/docs/eager/index.html#apply-functions-closures

Comment: This worked, thanks for your help. Although Rust seems a little unfriendly yet, I gotcha how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`replace_literal_all` method](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/trait.StringNameSpaceImpl.html#method.replace_literal_all). Note that this feature is flagged behind `strings` flag.

```
[dependencies]
polars = { version = "0.38.1", features = ["strings"] }
```

Then in your Rust code, you can do the transformation like this:

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut df = df! [
        "Id" => [1,2],
        "Text" => ["Some foo text", "Other text",],
    ]
    .unwrap();

    println!("Before = {:?}", df);
    let new_column = df["Text"]
        .str()
        .unwrap()
        .replace_literal_all("foo", "new_foo")
        .unwrap();

    let modified = df.with_column(new_column).unwrap();
    println!("After = {:?}", modified);
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Before = shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────┐
│ Id  ┆ Text          │
│ --- ┆ ---           │
│ i32 ┆ str           │
╞═════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ Some foo text │
│ 2   ┆ Other text    │
└─────┴───────────────┘
After = shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────────┐
│ Id  ┆ Text              │
│ --- ┆ ---               │
│ i32 ┆ str               │
╞═════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ Some new_foo text │
│ 2   ┆ Other text        │
└─────┴───────────────────┘
```

You can use [`replace_all` API](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/trait.StringNameSpaceImpl.html#method.replace_all) if you want regex based replacement(And please note that it requires [`regex` feature flag to be enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78117576/6699447)).