# Use replace_all() method in polars dataframe column

Tags: rust-polars

I'm trying to translate this polars-py code into polars-rs:

```
# python
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("my_text_column").str\
        .replace_all('some_literal', pl.col("my_other_text_column"), literal=True)
)
```

```
-- Rust
df = df.lazy().with_column(
    col("my_text_column").str()
    .replace_all(lit("some_literal"), col("my_other_text_column"), true)
).collect()?;
```

However, I get the error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `replace_all` found for struct `StringNameSpace` in the current scope
  --> src/alert_replicate.rs:38:10
   |
37 | /         col("my_text_column").str()
38 | |         .replace_all(lit("some_literal"), col("my_other_text_column"), true)
   | |         -^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `StringNameSpace`
   | |_________|
   |
```

The documentation for [polars::prelude::StringNameSpaceImpl::replace_all()](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/trait.StringNameSpaceImpl.html#method.replace_all) is not too enlightening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have "strings" in your features?

Comment: yes, i have features = ["lazy", "strings", "polars-ops", "replace"] and a few others that I believe are not relevant here

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is do `cargo clean` and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the source code for [polars-plan/src/dsl/string.rs](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/3cf4897e679b056d17a235d48867035265d43cdc/crates/polars-plan/src/dsl/string.rs) and found out the `replace_all` method requires the feature `regex`.

`cargo add polars --features regex` solved my problem. Adding this info to the documentation would be helpful.